# Query to Determine Remaining Unused Partitions in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does anyone know of a query to determine the number of remaining unused partitions in a table?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Look at [sys.partitions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175012(v=sql.110).aspx). There is a column named [rows]. This column `Indicates the approximate number of rows in this partition`. You could filter on `rows = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a query to list the empty partitions of a table, along with other relevant information.  This query is gleaned from the Partition Details SSMS custom report (https://ssmspartcustomrpt.codeplex.com/).  You can also use the out-of-the-box SSMS database-level Partition report to get this info.

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(p.object_id) AS ObjectName, 
    i.name AS IndexName, 
    p.index_id AS IndexID, 
    ds.name AS PartitionScheme, 
    p.partition_number AS PartitionNumber, 
    fg.name AS FileGroupName, 
    prv_left.value AS LowerBoundaryValue, 
    prv_right.value AS UpperBoundaryValue, 
    CASE pf.boundary_value_on_right WHEN 1 THEN 'RIGHT' ELSE 'LEFT' END AS PartitionFunctionRange, 
    p.rows AS Rows
FROM
    sys.partitions AS p INNER JOIN
    sys.indexes AS i ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id INNER JOIN
    sys.data_spaces AS ds ON ds.data_space_id = i.data_space_id INNER JOIN
    sys.partition_schemes AS ps ON ps.data_space_id = ds.data_space_id INNER JOIN
    sys.partition_functions AS pf ON pf.function_id = ps.function_id INNER JOIN
    sys.destination_data_spaces AS dds2 ON dds2.partition_scheme_id = ps.data_space_id AND dds2.destination_id = p.partition_number INNER JOIN
    sys.filegroups AS fg ON fg.data_space_id = dds2.data_space_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.partition_range_values AS prv_left ON ps.function_id = prv_left.function_id AND prv_left.boundary_id = p.partition_number - 1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    sys.partition_range_values AS prv_right ON ps.function_id = prv_right.function_id AND prv_right.boundary_id = p.partition_number
WHERE
    p.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')
    AND p.rows = 0;
```